# Error '! Missing = inserted for \ifnum' with cas-dc class

Tags: footnotes, titles, author, els-cas

## Background

I am currently working on submitting a journal manuscript and am trying to convert my original manuscript from `elsarticle` class to `cas-dc` based on feedback and recommendations from Elsevier. My code will successfully typeset my document *every other time*. It runs through, creates the following error message, I re-run and then it deletes the `.aux` file and successfully compiles.

**Error message**:`! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.`

Normally this would not be an issue but as @PhelypeOleinik pointed out in [his answer to my original question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/563069/194977), I need to successfully compile the document *twice* in order to get things like author and title notes to work.

### Similar questions

I have looked at the following answer/questions without much success:

- [Compilation problem with siunitx (returning error regarding ifnum)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422176/compilation-problem-with-siunitx-returning-error-regarding-ifnum): claims that it's an issue with how versions are maintained and dated, suggests that user update Tex distribution. **I have updated everything in MikTex and repeatedly checked for updates until no more updates were available. Issue persists.**
- [Missing=inserted for \ifnum](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519745/missing-inserted-for-ifnum): no answer suggests a potential issue with `beamer`. **I am not using `beamer`, do not think that it is an issue.**
- [Missing = inserted for \ifnum error when generating bibliography using natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413693/missing-inserted-for-ifnum-error-when-generating-bibliography-using-natbib) : suggests deleting the bib `aux` file and rerunning. **This wont work because I need to re-run without deleting the `aux` file in order to get all the notes to show up.**
- [Missing = inserted for \ifnum. \usepackage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471842/missing-inserted-for-ifnum-usepackage): alternately suggest look at the first answer in this list and updating packages/MikTex distribution. **I have already updated anything without success.**
- [Error “Missing = inserted for \ifnum”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320387/error-missing-inserted-for-ifnum): suggests that it is an issue with how the user was using `pgfmath` functions in `tikz` package. **In my MWE I am not using `tikz` directly (to my knowledge) and issue persists.**

## MWE

Below is a minimum working example that replicates the issue. I use `\input` a lot to keep separate files clean and have replicated that structure here in case that is somehow related. All of the separate files are in the same folder.

#### In `draft_paper.tex`

```
\listfiles

\documentclass[sort&compress]{cas-dc} 

\input{settings_options_parameters} % contains all of the settings/options that I don't think we'll need to change very often

\begin{document}

\input{frontmatter} 

\end{document}
```

#### In `settings_options_parameters.tex`

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_set:nn { stm / mktitle } { nologo }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

#### In `frontmatter.tex`

Based heavily on the documentation for `cas-dc` [here](https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/els-cas-templates/doc/elsdoc-cas.pdf).

```
\title[mode=title]{Test Title: 101 Reasons Why I Can't \LaTeX}

\tnotemark[1]

\tnotetext[1]{This document is the result of blood, sweat, tears and taxpayer money.}

\author[1]{Dummy Author One}[%
    type=author,
    orcid=]
\cormark[1]
\fnmark[1]
\ead[url]{mail@gmail.com, \url{fakewebaddress.com}}
\credit{Everything}
\address[1]{Nowheresville, North America}


\author[1]{Dummy Author Two}[%
    type=author,
    orcid=]
\cormark[2]
\fnmark[2]
\ead[url]{mailtwo@gmail.com, \url{phishingsupplies.com}}
\credit{Nothing}


\author[1]{Dummy Author Two}[%
    type=author,
    orcid=]
\cormark[1,2]
\fnmark[1,2]
\ead[url]{mailthree@gmail.com, \url{hackingsupplies.com}}
\credit{Nothing}
\address[1]{Nowheresville, North America}

\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}
\cortext[cor2]{Principal corresponding author}
\fntext[fn1]{This is the first author footnote. but is commonto third author as well.}
\fntext[fn2]{Another author footnote, this is a very longfootnote and it should be a really long footnote. But thisfootnote is not yet sufficiently long enough to make two linesof footnote text.}


% Abstract
\begin{abstract}[SUMMARY]
\lipsum[1-1]
\end{abstract}

% Key words
\begin{keywords}
\LaTeX \sep Science \sep Crying
\end{keywords}

\maketitle
```

## Results

These are images of the end result, the first time it compiles, the second time it throws the error mentioned above and it never shows the title notes `\tnotemark` or author notes `\cormark`

[image]
[image]

The `log` file after the error is thrown can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/WSkBDDAd). `\listfiles` has been added, but if anything else should be added please let me know.

Many thanks for any help on this issue!

Comment: Small nitpick: You say “Error message [...] Normally this would not be an issue”.  It would.  Error messages in a macro expansion language like TeX (especially low-level messages like that one) normally mean that something worse will happen down the road and you can't trust the output.  Fix the errors! :-)

Comment: Ha, I guess I am finally running up against the limitations of my 'ignore it and it will go away' approach!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`els-cas` has... issues.  You found two.

**First:** the optional document of `\cormark` *must* be a number, and it is *not* optional: if you leave it out you get an error. Yes :-)
`\cormark[]` is invalid, as is `\cormark[1,2]`, so in principle you cannot put more than one `\cormark` per author (who knows if it's by design or a bug).  Here's a patch to make the optional argument of `\cormark` really optional and allow `\cormark[1,2]` (add it yo your preamble):

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand \process@marks { }
   {
     \bool_lazy_or:nnTF
         { \cs_if_free_p:c { mark@corau\theauthor } }
         { \tl_if_empty_p:c { mark@corau\theauthor } }
       { \ignorespaces }
       { \str_set:Nx \l_tmpa_str { \use:c{ mark@corau\theauthor } }
         \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_str
           {
             \int_case:nn { ##1 }
               {
                 { 1 } { \sep$\ast$ }
                 { 2 } { \sep$\ast\ast$ }
                 { 3 } { \sep$\ast\!\ast\!\ast$ }
               }
               \tex_def:D \sep{\unskip,}
           }
         }
      \cs_if_free:cTF { mark@fnau\theauthor }
        { \ignorespaces }
        { \sep\use:c { mark@fnau\theauthor }
          \tex_def:D \sep{\unskip,}
        }
      }
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

**Second:** The optional argument of `\ead` does basically nothing. `\ead[url]{my@address.com}` is as valid as `\ead[mashed potatoes]{my@address.com}`. Yes :-)
The only difference is that if the optional argument is not empty, `els-cas` uses `\url`, otherwise it uses `\detokenize` around the argument. Doesn't make a lot of sense, if you ask me.  In any way, `\ead` does *not* (properly) support more than one address.

The documentation suggests you to use `\ead{my@address.com, another@mail.com}` and make one single URL out of the whole thing, which is wrong (but probably okay, since your paper will be edited by the Elsevier people and the LaTeX template won't be used in the process, so I'd probably go with that.

Another option is to use `\ead` twice, when you need two addresses:

```latex
\author[1]{Dummy Author Two}
\ead{mailthree@gmail.com} % e-mail adrress
\ead[mashed potatoes]{hackingsupplies.com} % website
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Although it will take me a good deal of time to parse out what your change to ```cormark``` actually does. Thanks again for all your help on this! It's a shame they're asking authors to use this class before ironing out all the bugs ...

Comment: @tjk8000 Yeah, I really don't see the point of this `els-cas` thingy, mainly because they use their own typesetting system (definitely not LaTeX), so `elsarticle` was good enough (and I doubt bugs will be fixed: the development seems to be stalled).  As for the patch, the original version treats the whole `mark@corau\theauthor` as a single number, so it breaks when you feed `1,2` to it. I just added a `\clist_map_inline:Nn` around the `\int_case:nn`, so it processes `1` and `2` separately.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. It was caused due to a missing `year` field in one of the BibTeX entries. I was able to fix the issue by adding the year field like this:

```
@online{arXiv,
    title = {arXiv.org e-Print archive},
    url = {https://arxiv.org/},
    author = {arXiv},
    year= {2023},
    urldate = {2023-08-07}
}
```